# What is the simplest way to send an Email?

Tags: delphi, email

I would like to send a simple email message from my Delphi program. More specifically, if my program encounters an exception I want to provide the option to send the error via any specified email address the user provides, of course been able to send an Email for any situation itself would be beneficial. Having the ability to send attachments is a bonus, but not required.

I have tried many examples found online but most don't seem to work. Some of them require parameters such as SMTP server etc, but how can my program determine this if my user can freely enter there own email address? Additionally I don't have a default email client installed on my PC, so if I am unable to send an email from my program then i am sure anyone else who uses my program will have the same problem.

So basically what I am asking is:

- How to send an email
- Attachments is not required, but would have its advantages
- How to handle things such as SMTP server, port numbers etc?
- If no default email client is installed, how to handle this

I hope my post is easy to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with the possible solutions, then explain why the alternatives are problematic at best:

#### Possible solutions

- Don't send eMail from the client computer, use a web service to pass the messages. No matter what technology is driving your web site, it can handle posted forms and it can send email. Simply POST your user's issue to your web service and have your web service send it to you using email or save it to a database. If the user thinks he is connected to the Internet he'll probably say so because his browser works, but that only says HTTP is working: SMTP might be blocked by the company firewall or by the ISP. This is my preferred solution.
- Send eMail using *your* SMTP server and your credentials. Sending the eMail *from the user's address* is highly unreliable. You can include your user's email address in a "REPLY TO" header or simply put it in the body of the message. You can do this using Indy components and since it's your SMTP server and your credentials you know all the details. As mentioned in the previous bullet, this might fail because SMTP might be blocked by the user's firewall or by the ISP's firewall.

#### About SMTP

First of all a few words about the SMTP protocol itself, because everything else is based on this:

- SMTP is **the** protocol for sending email. There are other implementation-specific protocols but all eMail servers are required to implement SMTP.
- SMTP was designed before the SPAM. It allows *any* computer to send email to *any* server. Absolutely no authentication is (theoretically) required to send an email message, and the server's SMTP server address is stored in DNS as MX record.
- SMTP itself includes absolutely no way of authenticating the sender, no attempt is made to check if the user really is the one in the "From" field.

#### What's the problem with sending eMail from the user's email address

The first option when sending eMail *from the user's address* is using the locally installed client and automation so they're presented with a ready-filled Outlook (or Firefox or whatever) email form and only need to click "Send". But you say you want your solution to work even with no local email installed, so this is not an option.

You mentioned you hope to achieve this asking the user for *only* her eMail address, no server details and I assume no username and password . The SMTP protocol actually allows this, because it has no built-in mechanism to authenticate the sender. SPAMers take grate advantage of this, and it's called "spoofing the sender address". To protect against this two things happened:

- SMTP hosts no longer accept eMail from anybody, they try to somehow authenticate the sending SMTP server. In other words, *your* SMTP server will reject the fake eMail you're sending to yourself! The proposed fix to this was to use SMTP relays. But then...
- SMTP relays no longer relay eMail from unknown users! SMTP itself doesn't offer any authentication mechanism, but the usual workaround is to first read email (because that part *does* require authentication) only then send eMail. This is done automatically by the sending SMTP component you might be using, but none the less, this requires a username and a password.

If this is not enough, think about it an other way: Do you expect anyone knowing *your email address* to be able to send email *from your email address*?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the program to send an email to you when an exception occurs, you ought to check out [MadExcept](http://www.madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm).  It will do that for you automatically, and include a full stack trace and other useful debug information.

Comment: Yes but if I know how to send an Email it will come in useful for other situations :)

Comment: Then you should edit your question. Think of other people, Craig, who will come along.

Comment: I will edit it, sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 2):

The unit JclMapi in the [JEDI Code Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/) contains two simple methods using the installed MAPI client:

```
function JclSimpleSendMail(const Recipient, Name, Subject, Body: AnsiString;
  const Attachment: TFileName = ''; ShowDialog: Boolean = True; ParentWND: THandle = 0;
  const ProfileName: AnsiString = ''; const Password: AnsiString = ''): Boolean;
```

and

```
function JclSimpleBringUpSendMailDialog(const Subject, Body: AnsiString;
  const Attachment: TFileName = ''; ParentWND: THandle = 0;
  const ProfileName: AnsiString = ''; const Password: AnsiString = ''): Boolean;
```

No need to configure server etc in Delphi - the settings of the installed client will be used.

This simple solution however does not work if no mail client is installed. Sorry for answering too quickly.

Another option would be to provide a public web server (I did it with Google App Engine) which can be used from the Delphi app as an email gateway, by sending a HTTP request. This can be done with Indy, and as clients which have Internet access usually are able to perform HTTP requests, it does not require special configurations as SMTP clients are not always allowed to go through a corporate firewall.

The madExcept library provides the same transfer method (sending via HTTP) as it only needs the server address as a constant defined in the application.

Comment: I tried the method you posted, unfortunately I get this message:

"There is no email program associated to perform the requested action. Please install an email program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel." Seems I need Outlook installed

Comment: love this answer, as it uses the config of the default email program. You can use this to get the proper server names and then Use @Tim's answer as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

If you have and know the name of your email host use the TidSMTP component. Part of the indy clients.

Then call this filling it out with your info

```
Email.QuickSend('mail.YourEmailHost.com','Title','Addressed To',
                'Where_the_email_looks_like_it_came_from@YourDomain.com','EmailText');
```

Comment: If my user can input their email address freely then I dont know the host, so I must need to interpret it or something.

Comment: Don't quote me on this but I think if you have a valid host to use that you could let any one using your program use your email host. I haven't tested this but I'll look into it. If this does work then all you'd need them to do is enter the email address.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would be kind of like relaying the email from my email host, to the recipients whatever the destination address.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most easiest way to send email is using Windows Collaboration Data Objects (CDO).  An alternate way is using Indy's component but I dislike it's huge binary file size.

Before using CDO, import type library from c:\windows\system32\cdosys.dll.  The following example shows how to use CDO to send email:

```
uses CDO_TLB;

var M: IMessage;
    s: string;
begin
  M := CoMessage.Create;
  M.From := 'from-email@host.com';
  M.To_ := 'to-email@host.com';
  M.Subject := 'This is subject';
  M.TextBody := 'This is text body';

  s := 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/';
  with M.Configuration.Fields do begin
    Item[s + 'sendusing'].Value := cdoPostUsingPort;
    Item[s + 'smtpserver'].Value := 'smtp.host.com';
    Item[s + 'smtpauthenticate'].Value := cdoBasic;
    Item[s + 'sendusername'].Value := 'user_name';
    Item[s + 'sendpassword'].Value := 'password';
    Item[s + 'smtpserverport'].Value := 587;
    Item[s + 'smtpusessl'].Value := False;
    Item[s + 'smtpconnectiontimeout'].Value := 5;  // default is 30 seconds
    Update;
  end;

  try
    M.Send;
    // success
  except
    // fail
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```